# No se me guardar las variaciones en woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de crear las variaciones de los productos con código, yo creo un array llamado $options_variant el cual tiene los atributos con sus opciones, pero parece que no se estan pasando bien en el metodo set_attributes() o quizas halla otro problema que no este viendo, les dejo mi codigo:

```
// Hacemos una llamada para obtener las diferentes variantes que tiene el producto
                $info_variant = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_post('https://api.sinaliteuppy.com/price/' . $product_id . '/us', $args2));
                $info_variant = json_decode( $info_variant );
    
                $price_variant = (float)$info_variant->price;
                $options_variant = (array)$info_variant->productOptions;

// Estan son los atributos para las variaciones 
//                  array(6) {
//                ["Stock"]=>
//                string(26) "14PT Printed 2 Sides (4/4)"
//                ["size"]=>
//                string(7) "3.5 x 2"
//                ["qty"]=>
//                string(2) "25"
//                ["Coating"]=>
//                string(10) "No Coating"
//                ["Round Corners"]=>
//                string(3) "YES"
//                ["Turnaround"]=>
//                string(19) "2 - 3 Business Days"
//              }
    
                $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
                $variation->set_parent_id( $product_id );
                $variation->set_attributes( $options_variant );
                $variation->set_regular_price( $price_variant );
                $variation->save();
```